# postGIS, length, area, density of line network

Tags: postgis

I am trying to figure out the length and density of all major roads and minor roads within a study area to return something like:

```
|STUDYAREA|a_road_length|a_road_density|other_road_length|other_road_density
```

There are two polygons within the study area - an inner focus and an outer buffer.  I want the length and density grouped by these two areas.
Major roads are only one type (a_roads) but other roads are stored in two different relations

```
|a_road|name|geom

|b_road|name|geom

|minor_road|name|geom
```

So far I can get the length of each separately using ST_Length, the area of the polygons using ST_Area and the density of a_road but not all the elements for all the roads together in one result.

Perhaps need to use subquery or

```
create VIEW
```

but unsure how to put all these elements together.

[image]

In the example above red line length and density for inner and outer area then combine green and yellow length and density for inner and outer area to return as "other roads".

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is "merge" all roads in a single "table".

For each road type table, create a query that returns the exact same data structure. Having them all in an exact same structure, you can use [UNION ALL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html) to combine the queries. You can put that inside a [WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) clause and then use it as if it was a single table, and perform your queries. Something like this:

```sql
WITH all_roads as
  (SELECT
       name, geom
   FROM
       a_road
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
       name, geom
   FROM
       b_road
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
       name, geom
   FROM
       minor_road)
SELECT
... --do your stuff
FROM
    all_roads, 
    study_area
```